# Fasttext - Color Name Classification - Getting '</s>' as model.words

Tags: python, fasttext

I am currently working on a translation layer to translate numerous unique color names into a common color name.  Example being METALLIC RED would be RED and NAVY BLUE would be BLUE.  I have a list of colors from a source I'm trying to translate and a base set of color names I would like them identified as.  Currently fasttext when a build a model, supervised or unsupervised I'm getting the model.words as [''] no matter if I label the lines or not. I've tried to remove all special characters, etc in the words. I'm using the fasttext library and

I've tried to converting my dataset to include labels from my dataframe:

```
__label__beige beige
__label__black black
__label__blue blue
__label__brown blue
__label__gold gold
__label__gray gray
__label__green green
__label__orange orange
__label__purple purple
__label__red red
__label__silver silver
__label__white white
__label__yellow yellow
__label__other other
```

I've tried to remove the labels as well.

```py
import joblib
import fasttext
import numpy as np
from pyfasttext import FastText
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

model = fasttext.train_unsupervised('base_colors.txt')
```

Shows all the base colors I've listed.

I would expect when running model.words I would get:

beige
black
blue
brown
gold
gray
green
orange
purple
red
silver
white
yellow
other

Instead I'm getting:

```py
['</s>']
```

Example of a dataset I'm trying to translate:

```
ultra silv met
sunrise orange
polo grn met
red jewel tint
charcaol
cream ivory
lt driftwd met
blue mist
silvermist
charoal
3gcpkte77dg146719
blue granilte met
steele green
cosmic silv
whitwe diamond
blue granit
```

Solution.  Using a pretrained vector along with the input with multiple colors labeled.

```
./fasttext supervised -input base_colors.txt -output model -pretrainedVectors cc.en.300.vec -dim 300
```

Comment: FYI to anyone later wondering, `'</s>'` is EOS from the code I was just reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you aren't properly using fasttext.

**a.** First of all, my advice is to use [official fasttext python binding](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/python) (pyfasttext is no longer mantained).

**b.** For your purpose, I think that you have to provide a training corpus, made in the following way...

> __label__basecolor your_color_expression
>
> (example: __label__red metallic red)

...then train a supervised model (following [this tutorial](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html)). So the classificator (the model) will learn relations between complex color names and base colors.

***c.*** If your training dataset is small, you can start from [FastText pretrained vectors](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html), making the classificator start with some preexisting knowledge.

*So, you can follow these steps:*

***c.1.*** Download pretrained vectors (.vec) from fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html;

***c.2.*** Train your model using: ./fasttext supervised -input base_colors.txt -output model -pretrainedVectors cc.en.300.vec -dim 300.

***c.3.*** Now your model is much better!

Comment: Anakin87 Thank you for taking the time to review my post.  I used the pyfasttext because it had access to the nearest neighbor unsupervised which the official one doesn't. I have 11,000+ colors in the dataset which range from jet_black black_crystal .  It would be impossible for me to classify 11,000.  What I'm reading is to use the pretrained vector then to classify the crazy colors I have.

Comment: I'm just wondering how do I classify 11,000 different colors without putting a __label__red metallic red in front of them.  It seems like a lot of manual classification to build the model

Comment: You can manually prepare a training dataset with a few hundred lines, then train the model starting from pretrained vectors (hoping that it will help with unlabelled color names). Then you can test model's performance on other unknown color names.

Comment: https://github.com/dennoio/fasttext/blob/master/base_colors.txt
I created this from the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors_by_shade to do a training set but like before I tried to train the model and got '</str>' I'm sure it's some word txt encoding I'm just not seeing

Comment: fasttext predict-prob base_colors.bin -

red
__label__green 0.132813
blue
__label__green 0.134766
GREEN
__label__green 0.175781
RED
__label__green 0.175781
BLACK
__label__green 0.175781

Comment: Since your training corpus is small, you have to start from pretrained vectors:

Download pretrained vectors (.vec) from https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html;

Train your model using:  ./fasttext supervised -input base_colors.txt -output model -pretrainedVectors cc.en.300.vec -dim 300.

Now your model is much better!

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try and let you know what I find out

Comment: You should add that as your answer.